# python set of class objetcs add + search min/max

Tags: python, object, set

NI got a bit stuck with object in a Set in Python.

**I have a test script which works:**

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, pos, parent, g , h):
        self.pos = pos
        self.parent = parent
        self.g = g
        self.h = h
        self.f = g+h

openlist=set()
openlist.add(node((1,1),None,1,5))

for node in openlist: print node.pos
```

**my actual code doesn't work**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

class node:
    def __init__(self, pos, parent, g , h):
        self.pos = pos
        self.parent = parent
        self.g = g
        self.h = h
        self.f = g+h

class NewAMap(object):
    def __init__(self, size, start, target):
        self.size = size
        self.start = start
        self.target = target
        self.openlist = set()
        self.closedlist = set()
        self.EmptyValue = 0

        self.clear()
        self.addStart(self.start)
        self.addTarget(self.target)

    def clear(self):
        #self.OccMap = [[self.EmptyValue for i in xrange(self.sizeY)] for j in xrange(self.sizeX)]
        self.OccMap = np.zeros(shape=(self.size[0],self.size[1]),dtype=int)
    def display(self):
        print np.swapaxes(self.OccMap,0,1)
        #print self.open
        print self.closed
        self.PicMap = np.zeros(shape=(self.size[0],self.size[1]),dtype=(float,3))
        for x in xrange(0,self.size[0]):
            for y in xrange(0,self.size[1]):
                if self.OccMap[x][y] == 0:
                    self.PicMap[y][x]=(1,1,1)
                elif self.OccMap[x][y] == -1:
                    self.PicMap[y][x]=(0,0,0)
                elif self.OccMap[x][y] == -2:
                    self.PicMap[y][x]=(1,0,0)
                elif self.OccMap[x][y] == -3:
                    self.PicMap[y][x]=(0,0,1)
        #print self.PicMap
        plt.imshow(self.PicMap, interpolation='nearest')
        plt.show()

    def addBlocked(self, blockposs):
        self.OccMap[blockposs[0]][blockposs[1]]=-1
    def addStart(self, start):
        self.OccMap[start[0]][start[1]]=-2
    def addTarget(self, target):
        self.OccMap[target[0]][target[1]]=-3
    def calcRoute(self):
        self.openlist.add(node(self.start, None, 0, 0))
        for node in elfopenlist: print node.pos, node.parent, node.g, node.h, node.f


def main():
    AMap = NewAMap((20,20),(1,12),(12,12))
    for y in range(8,17): AMap.addBlocked((8,y))
    AMap.calcRoute()
    AMap.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It fails with the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment
The error occures in AMap.calcRoute():

```
self.openlist.add(node(self.start, self.none, 0, 0))
```

I think that's because I try to use the node object out of the NewAMap object. But how do I do this correctly?

I would also like to know how I:

**1: check if an object is in the set**

I would like to check if an object with node.pos is in the set.

**2: search for the object in the set with the lowest node.f value.**

I would like to search for the object in the Set with the lowest node.f value. Eventuelly remove it from the Set or update a value.

How can I do this? Is it the/a correct approach at all?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Always show the specific code that leads to the error! Could you please update your question?

Comment: `local variable 'node' referenced before assignment` means that at the place you are using the term `node` it is not known yet.  Maybe you have the declaration of the class below its usage?  That's not possible in Python.

Comment: To make this clear:  After the class `node` has been created, you should be able to do things like `openlist.add(node((1,1),(0,0),5,1))`.  The problem must be in something you haven't told us.

Comment: Don't use the `sets` module. It's deprecated; they made a built-in `set` class that works better.

Comment: Thanks. Changed from the sets module to the builtin set class. My main problem/misstake is still there.

Comment: I played arrounf with it a bit. "self.openlist.append(node(self.start, None, 0, 0))" works if I put it in __init__ of the NewAMap class but doesn't work if I put it in the calcRoute(self) function. What do I miss?

Comment: ok, found the problem. The debuger stated the wrong line as beeing wrong. It is actually this line: for node in elfopenlist: print node.pos, node.parent, node.g, node.h, node.f   -  I use node as instance for the iteration but is is the class name. So I changed it to item -- and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, what you can do is create a global variable called node_object at the top of your file. You can repeatedly reference it with the node object you create dynamically and add it to openlist.

As for the second, of course you can do that. Check the docs for [sets in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). However, IMHO it's a better idea to use a different data structure that uses sequence-like behavior - maybe a list unless you are looking to deal with uniqueness of elements.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to iterate through a whole list to check if an object is in and edit/remove it. I think I read that a set is faster for this?

Comment: Membership testing is the same for set as it is for a list. You can do a if x in sample_list for a list too.

Comment: OK. cool. How can I test for an object with a specific attribute beeing in the list without iterating through it?

Comment: For a specific attribute, I believe you would have to traverse the entire list...